# Refer to Sheet with value in Cell?

Tags: google-sheets

The usual way to reference a sheet is [here](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1361471&answer=75943) but how do you reference a sheet when the sheet's name is a value in a cell?

For example,

```
A1 = "Sheet number two"
B1 = A1&"!B4"
```

Here I want B1 to display the value in `'Sheet number two'!B4` but it's not working for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use the `indirect()` formula. So in cell `B1` you need to put this formula:

```
=indirect(A1&"!B4")
```

Comment: A problem with this is if you copy B1 to C1, it won't check B5 in referred sheet as expected. Because B4 is a string... any remedy?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the values need to be outside the speechmarks otherwise it doesn’t reference the other sheet.

```
=indirect(A1&”!”&B4)
```

Comment: Typographic quotes doesn't work in formulas, only straight quotes, beside that the proposed formula was already in the [previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/158302/88163) that was posted 9 years ago!