# Using a cell text as sheet reference

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use a cell text as a sheet reference in Google sheets. I have a spreadsheet with many sheets and want to reference a sheet name from text in a cell rather than having to put the sheet name in each time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refer to Sheet with value in Cell?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24477/refer-to-sheet-with-value-in-cell)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat guessing what you require (examples often help) if say you have a couple of sheets named:

> Sheet2
>   Sheet3

and those names in A1 and A2 of Sheet1, then a formula like:

```
=indirect(A1&"!B2")
```

in Sheet1 should return the value of B2 from Sheet2 and if copied down one row, the value of B2 from Sheet3.