# How to use a cell text in a formula to select a different sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have read through a few of these on here and they are saying to use indirect():

- [Refer to Sheet with value in Cell?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24477/refer-to-sheet-with-value-in-cell)
- [Using a cell text as sheet reference](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/72580/using-a-cell-text-as-sheet-reference)

I am not having any luck.

```
=COUNTIF(JAN!$C$4:$C$102,B5)
```

This formula works but when I try to get D2 in there for JAN or FEB, I can't get it to work.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT('D2' & "!" & $C$4:$C$102),B5)
```

D2 is a drop down data validation select from items to select JAN.,

How do I get D2 to equal JAN in the formula so it works with selecting the drop down selection?

Comment: Instead of  `'D2'` use `D2`, and instead of  `"!" & $C$4:$C$102` use `"!$C$4:$C$102"`

Answer (score -1):

I eventually used:

```
=COUNTIF(indirect(D2&"!$C$4:$C$102"),B5)
```

Comment: If you want to merge your unregistered account into your new one so you'll regain access to the question use the [contact us](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/contact) form.